# adf managed bean retrieving a value from input text

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I'm trying to retrieve a value from an input text in my jsf page, but when I change its value it doesn't change in the managed bean.

here's the input text:

```
<af:inputText label="Código:" id="codigo" value="#{tipoBaixaBean.codigo}"/>
```

and my managed bean is annotated like this:

```
@ManagedBean 
@RequestScoped
public class TipoBaixaBean {

private long codigo;
```

I have the getters and setters, but the value of the property "codigo" never changes,
What would be the problem??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your Bean scope to 'pageFlowScope' or 'viewScope' in adfc-config.xml . That should do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say when you are trying to get the value...on page submit or when you tab out of the field. If you want the value when you tab out (lose focus) then set the autoSubmit property on the input text field to true.
I would also suggest using a print statement in set method to make sure it's being called. The scope issue only arises if you are trying to retain the value between page requests.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how can you bind an inputText to a long object in backing bean.

Ideally it should be something like

```
private RichInputText codigo;
```

you can get the value of codigo using the getter.

```
getCodigo.inputValue();
```

I don't think scope will cause any problem. It works for the least life scope i.e. backing bean scope.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the exact moment in which you are getting/setting the value, but if you need to do it automatically every time a change occurs, then you'll need to implement the Value Change Listener. Check this out: [Value Change Listener example](http://www.awasthiashish.com/2014/04/get-updated-model-values-in-value.html)